# Make a function affect each quiz ID separately

Tags: javascript

I have made a multiple choice quiz and when there is one on a single page it works exactly as I want it to. The issue is that I need to have multiple quizzes appear on one page and the behaviour on one quiz is affecting the behaviour of any other quizzes that appear on that same page

I've been looking online to see if there's a way for the function to handle each quiz ID separately (as if they each had their own separate function) but nothing I've found so far looks to be something I can apply to the function I already have.

Here's the Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.answer').click(function(event){
        jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');   
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="Quiz1" class="quiz">
    <div class="question">Is this a really good question?</div>
    <div class="interaction">
        <div class="answer" data-answer="correct">
            <div class="answer-content">
                <span>Answer 1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="answer" data-answer="wrong1">
            <div class="answer-content">
                <span>Answer 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="answer" data-answer="wrong2">
            <div class="answer-content">
                <span>Answer 3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="response-text correct">Correct</div>
        <div class="response-text wrong1">Wrong 1</div>
        <div class="response-text wrong2">Wrong 2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Quiz2" class="quiz">
    <div class="question">Is this a really good question?</div>
    <div class="interaction">
        <div class="answer" data-answer="correct">
            <div class="answer-content">
                <span>Answer 1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="answer" data-answer="wrong1">
            <div class="answer-content">
                <span>Answer 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="answer" data-answer="wrong2">
            <div class="answer-content">
                <span>Answer 3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="response-text correct">Correct</div>
        <div class="response-text wrong1">Wrong 1</div>
        <div class="response-text wrong2">Wrong 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.answer[data-answer="correct"] ~ .correct {
    display:none;
}
.answer.active[data-answer="correct"] ~ .correct { 
    display:block
}

.answer[data-answer="wrong1"] ~ .wrong1 {
    display:none;
}
.answer.active[data-answer="wrong1"] ~ .wrong1 { 
    display:block
}

.answer[data-answer="wrong2"] ~ .wrong2 {
    display:none;
}
.answer.active[data-answer="wrong2"] ~ .wrong2 { 
    display:block
}
```

So, with one quiz on the page everything works as expected - Clicking each bubble will give the user a corresponding response: Correct, Wrong, Wrong2. As each bubble is clicked the css takes whichever .answer element has the .active class and displays the corresponding answer response based on the data-attribute given.

This is wonderful until I have more than one quiz on the page

When there are two quizzes on one page and you click the bubbles in the second quiz it will remove the last answer response from the quiz above it.

I need each quiz to act independently and not have one quiz affecting the others.

I hope this makes sense, I'm terrible at explaining myself.

I've set up a fiddle so you can see it in action - https://jsfiddle.net/g8qpvtcz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you just want to be able to display more than one "response box"?

If so, this might do the job for you:

In your fiddle, change line 3 of the javascript:

```js
jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
```

to

```js
jQuery(this).parent().children('.active').removeClass('active');
```

This gets the parent element of the clicked answer (i.e. the `div.interaction`) for the given quiz and only removes the `active` class in its children.

**Edit**
You could also just use the `siblings()` method. Which would be even prettier. Don't really know why I forgot about that one.

```js
jQuery(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks again, I've used your edit instead. Trying to get into the habit of keeping this is clean as possible :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! If you just want feedback to be visual, you can simplify the structure of html/css a bit, like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnt7s9vj/1/). It removes the need for separate wrong1/wrong2 classes and makes your css selectors simpler.

Comment: That's brilliant! My only issue is that each response will need to appear below a row of possible answers that appear inline as bubbles - I've added the rest of my CSS to this fiddle here - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AaronMassingham/36bumd70/2/)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, a bit more tricky then. I personally prefer my structure. Using that, you can solve your problem by using a "dummy feedback element" (a sibling to .answer) and through jQuery show the correct feedback. Like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nscuzw7m/2/).

Comment: That's cool. I think I'll utilise this latest fiddle instead and try to learn more from it. Thanks so much for your help on this @Morsby much appreciated!